# How to get a product title from a web page using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have now been able to search google and obtain different links of  different PDP's (product detail pages) and I want to scrape the product titles of these pages. However I am having some trouble understanding exactly how to understand the product title html code.

Below is my code:

```
Sub testing()


Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim x As Integer
Dim x1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim Product_Title As String
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement



ie.Navigate "https://www.johnlewis.com/asus-zenbook-ux331un-eg009t-laptop-intel- core-i5-8gb-256gb-ssd-geforce-mx150-13-3-royal-blue/p3405316"

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


  Product_Title = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("product-header__title")


   Debug.Print (Product_Title)
```

But I get [object HTMLHeadingElement] as an output instead of the product title

here is the html code:

```
<h1 class="product-header__title" itemprop="name">ASUS ZenBook S UX391UA-ET087T Laptop, Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, 13.3”, Full HD, Burgundy</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `.innerText` property and to index into the collection returned when matching on class name.

```
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("product-header__title")(0).innerText
```

As is the first with that class name you can also use:

```
ie.document.querySelector(".product-header__title").innerText
```

The `.` is a CSS [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and [`querySelector`](http://mozilla.org) method applies this to the DOM document and returns the first match.

Note that as a collection is being returned with your syntax you would require:

```
Dim Product_Title As Object
Set Product_Title = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("product-header__title")
```

Then to index in with `Product_Title(0).innerText`. I am not a fan of underscores in local variable names so I would just use `productTitle`; also, notice the change in casing.

---

If you are only after the title it would be faster to issue an [XMLHTTP request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/), rather than opening an IE browser instance:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTitle()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.johnlewis.com/asus-zenbook-ux331un-eg009t-laptop-intel-%20core-i5-8gb-256gb-ssd-geforce-mx150-13-3-royal-blue/p3405316", False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Debug.Print .querySelector(".product-header__title").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library